# Is it possible to run Audio file alternatively in two ear phone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avfoundation

I have to run Audio file alternatively in right and left ear phone ? I have process sound such that it will heard right and left both alternatively?

Comment: I think it's more relevant to audio file itself, rather than programming.

Comment: how in audio file will play in two different ear phone alternatively in ios?
I have a sound file as hearing aid i have to check in which ear it is playing?

Comment: Not sure that I understands you question correctly. But if you want to be able to select (or set) some definite channel to play your audio file. For example left/right in case of  earphones then it's definitely possible. Al least using AudioUnit on low level. Or AudioQueue on higher level (see CoreAudio documentation for details)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To direct Audio to either the left or right speaker, you use the .pan property of AVAudioPlayer. You can balance it in the center (the default of 0.0) or send it all left (-1.0) or all right (1.0)

https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudioplayer/1390884-pan